# How to get the precise result after adding floating point numbers in Python?

Tags: python

Given a pickled file - ***log.dat***, containing ***list of strings***. I wrote a pythonic function that reads the file and looks for a line of the form,

```
Xerror: 0.xxxx
```

Whenever such line is encountered, I have to extract the ***floating-point value*** and compute the total of these error values. When i reach the ***EOF***, i need to print the total number of such error lines and average of error value.

***log.dat***

```
Xerror: 0.2395
0.00001000ems
Xerror: 0.2785
ggn0.000990909
Xerror: 0.2567
xsddtd0.98789
Xerror: 0.2245
Xerror: 0.2000
Xerror: 0.2563
```

***Pythonic program:***

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
textFile = "page06.txt"

if os.path.isfile(textFile):
    ln = find = 0
    total = 0.0000

    fileobj = open(textFile)
    while True:
        line = fileobj.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        else:
            print(line , end="")
            ln += 1
            substring = "Xerror:"
            flag = substring in line

            if flag:
                find += 1


                length = len(line)
                index = line.index(".")
                result = line[index:length]
                num = float(result)
                total = total + num                  

    print()
    print("Total Lines: %d" %ln)
    print("Total Lines which represent error: %d" %find)
    print("Total sum of floating-point numbers: %f" %total)
    fileobj.close()
else:
    print ("File does not exist")
```

I am not getting the exact precise which my requirement is after extracting and adding these from the file

```
0.2395 + 0.2785 + 0.2567 +  0.2245 + 0.2000 + 0.2563
```

How will I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly (or precisely) does *"I am not getting the exact precise which my requirement is"* **mean**? Floating point numbers are inevitably an approximation; you can't represent infinitely many real numbers with a finite number of bits.

Comment: Look into the ``decimal`` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: `awk -F: '$1 == "Xerror" { count++; sum+=$2 } END { print count, sum/count }' mylogfile.txt`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the %f format to %.4f. This will output the answer with 4 decimal digits which is all your data set warrants.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `decimal` module. Instead of converting the numbers to float, you do

```
import decimal
... 
    total = decimal.Decimal(0)
    ...
        num = decimal.Decimal(result)
```